# QGIS 3.0.3 python error "/bin/sh: gdal_polygonize.py: command not found"

Tags: python, raster, gdal, convert, polygonize

I have recently downloaded QGIS on my Mac to preform an analysis for my dissertation.

I am trying to convert my raster data to polygon data using the gdal_polygonize.py tool provided by QGIS.

Whenever I try to use any of the gdal software I get the error message:
"/bin/sh: gdal_polygonize.py: command not found"

Can anyone help me solve this problem? 
I really need to use this feature for my analysis.

Comment: did you install the qgis-python package?

Comment: I have python 3.6.5 installed on my computer and I downloaded the packages which were provided with the QGIS download. Is there a separate qgis-python package I need to install?

Comment: I don't know about Macs but there is on proper unix boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Xubuntu 18.04 and installed QGIS 3.4
I have the same message when I want to convert raster image to polygone.
executing give this answer:
GDAL command:
gdal_polygonize.py /home/tec/Documents/QGISdata/AdnMarseille/GeoTiff/AdnPtEt4kW67dB.tif /tmp/processing_cf2a6bfaede3420da00aeb236e0c592d/37a5a44485004d109c76619232bf7bb1/OUTPUT.shp -b 3 -f "ESRI Shapefile" None DN
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: 1: gdal_polygonize.py: not found

with older version of QGIS it works fine when the names of files are short and the color image is bue.